# DSpace Cris 4 Internal System Error after login

Tags: dspace

I have just installed DSpace Cris 4. However, I cannot login with the administrator account or complete a registration as it shows Internal System Error. I have tested if it was a problem with my database connection but it wasn't because it could check if the username or password was valid or not.

After checking the logs, I found out that the problem was the column researcher0_.sourceref does not exist but I had no idea how to solve this problem in Dspace cris 4.

Does anyone have any idea on which file I should modify? 
Thank you for your help.

Here are the messages shown in dspace.log

> 2014-09-25 12:02:13,799
>   INFO  org.dspace.authenticate.PasswordAuthentication @ anonymous:session_id=80CE880BB2219B91D5669975E7DFBFA2:ip_addr=xxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxx:authenticate:attempting password auth of user=email@xxx.com
>   2014-09-25 12:02:13,814 WARN  org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper @ SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42703
>   2014-09-25 12:02:13,814 ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper @ ERROR: column researcher0_.sourceref does not exist
>     Position: 103

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got my answer from a very kind person.

The problem was I had an incomplete database.

After updating/altering the database, everything works fine.

Given links to the sqls to run:

h.t.t.p.s://github.com/Cineca/DSpace/blob/dspace-cris-master/dspace/etc/{database}/addon-crismodule.sql

h.t.t.p.s://github.com/Cineca/DSpace/blob/dspace-cris-master/dspace/etc/{database}/update-crismodule_321_to_4.sql

Replace {database} with oracle or postgres, depending on what you are using and remove the dots in the link.

Actual commands I used since I was using Linux:

psql -h localhost -d dspace -U dspace -f dspace/etc/postgres/addon-crismodule.sql

psql -h localhost -d dspace -U dspace -f dspace/etc/postgres/update-crismodule_321_to_4.sql

Original link to the solution:
http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.db.dspace.user/27811